# Auto answer ssh-copy-id in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, scripting

I'm writting a shell script and I want to automate login into a remote machine    using **ssh-copy-id**, so manually when I print :

```
ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa $2@$4 -p $3 | echo $1
```

$1 refer to **password**,
 $2 refer to **username**,
 $3 refer to **port**, and
 $4 refer to **ip**, 
It is ok with that, the problem is that I have to automate inserting password after :

```
ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa $2@$4 -p $3
```

I add this "**| printf $1**", but it does not work it shows "**password:**" in the screen and still wait for the password .. 
I hope you understand me and thank you.

Comment: I don't see why you need to automate `ssh-copy-id` like that. `ssh-copy-id` is used to enable logging in to remote ssh server via a ssh key. That is, you execute `ssh-copy-id` _once_, and then login normally using `ssh`.

Comment: I have a lot of servers, and every week a lot of servers comes so, that's why I want to automate logging.

Comment: Try the other way around: `echo $1|ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa $2@$4 -p $3`

Comment: still not working ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding the Password in the Bash Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242031/embedding-the-password-in-the-bash-script)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that. `ssh-copy-id` is used when we want to setup a key-based authentication and we haven't done that already. So the solution from that thread does not help in this case.

Answer (score 3):

As @Leon pointed out, you had the pipeline backwards. But even if you do it with the correct order, it will still not work because `ssh-copy-id` (and all other programs from `openssh`) do not read passwords from their `stdin`. The solution is to use the `$SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable. You can do that as follows: first, create an auxiliary script, say `/var/tmp/ssh-pass.sh` (actually find a better name than that), with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                    
echo "$PASS"
```

Then you can use the following command to accomplish what you've asked for:

```
PASS="$1" SSH_ASKPASS="/var/tmp/ssh-pass.sh" setsid -w ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa "$2"@"$4" -p "$3"
```

**Explanation**: we use `setsid -w` to disassociate the `ssh-copy-id` process from the currently used terminal. That forces `ssh-copy-id` to run the executable specified in the `$SSH_ASKPASS` in order to obtain the password. We have specified our own script in that variable, so `ssh-copy-id` will execute just that. Now the script is supposed to provide the password to `ssh-copy-id` by printing it to its stdout. We use the `$PASS` variable to the password to the script, so the script just prints that variable.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the auxiliary script, i.e. `... SSH_ASKPASS="$(echo \"$PASS\")" set-copy-id ...`? That is to say, to make the script self-contained?

Comment: It doesn't look like it: openssh expects that `SSH_ASKPASS` contains the name or path of an executable file because it uses the [execlp](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/25c8a2bbcc10c493d27faea57c42a6bf13fa51f2/readpass.c#L80) function to run it and it doesn't give you a way to pass custom arguments to it.

Answer (score 1):

2020 / Mac OS X:

Install sshpass [(original answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623099/10798643)

```sh
brew install hudochenkov/sshpass/sshpass
```

Run `ssh-copy-id` using `sshpass` and with the password as an arg

```sh
sshpass -p $1 ssh-copy-id -i ~/PATH/TO/KEY $2@$4 -p $3
```

If you want to turn off strict host checking as well, use the `-o` flag, which is passed to the underlying ssh:

```sh
sshpass -p hunter2 ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/PATH/TO/KEY $2@$4 -p $3
```

I tried the solution by @redneb, and installed `setsid` through util-linux by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55769823/10798643), but kept receiving a password denied.

I found this strategy to work for uploading my SSH key while setting up multiple raspberry pis in successino. In my script, I also run `ssh-keygen -R raspberrypi.local` each time too, to avoid the `The ECDSA host key for raspberrypi.local has changed` error.